# Inheritance with "virtual" classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, inner-classes, minimax

I am currently trying to code a generic minmax algorithm.
I am fairly new to c++ with background in c and arm asm programming.
For the MinMax-Algorithm im using a variant called the Negamax, which makes it a little more compact:

```
#define move typename game<evaluationtype>::_move
#define gamestate typename game<evaluationtype>::_gamestate
#define player typename game<evaluationtype>::_player


template <typename gametype, typename evaluationtype>
std::pair<evaluationtype, move> Negamax(game <evaluationtype> Game, int depth, evaluationtype alpha, evaluationtype beta) {
    if (depth == 0)
        return std::make_pair(Game.evaluation(), move());
    else {
        move savebestmove;
        evaluationtype maxValue = alpha;
        std::list<move> allpossiblemoves = Game.getpossiblemoves();
        for (move Move : allpossiblemoves) {
            gamestate state = Game.makemove(Move);
            evaluationtype checkvalue = -((Negamax<gametype, evaluationtype>(Game, depth - 1, -beta, -maxValue)).first);
            Game.undomove(Move, state);
            if (checkvalue > maxValue) {
                maxValue = checkvalue;
                savebestmove = Move;
                if (maxValue >= beta)
                    break;
            }
        }
        return std::make_pair(maxValue, savebestmove);
    }
}
#undef move
#undef gamestate
#undef player
```

In the Code im setting required member functions for the base class of games, which could look like:

```
    template <typename evaluationtype>
class game {
    enum class _player;
    class _move;
    class _gamestate;
private:
    _player playersturn;
public:
    game() = delete;
    virtual evaluationtype evaluation() const;
    virtual std::list<_move>&& getpossiblemoves() const;
    virtual _gamestate makemove(const _move&);
    virtual void undomove(const _move&, const _gamestate&);
};
```

Now Im trying to implement a derived class with a Tic-Tac-Toe game:

```
template <typename evaluationtype>
class TicTacToe : game<evaluationtype> {
private:
    enum class _player {
        none, cross, circle
    };
    class _move {
        unsigned x;
        unsigned y;
    };
    class _gamestate {
        std::array<std::array<_player, 3> ,3> field;
        _player turn = cross;
    };
    _gamestate currentfield;
public:
    TicTacToe(); 
    evaluationtype evaluation() const;
    std::list<_move>&& getpossiblemoves() const;
    _gamestate makemove(const _move&);
    void undomove(const _move&, const _gamestate&);
};
```

The only method with definition is currently an empty constructor. Visual Studio isnt showing me any errors, but as soon as Im trying to create an instance of TicTacToe, i get this output:

```
1>C:\AlphaBetaNegamax\TicTacToe.h(17,3): error C2079: 'TicTacToe<int>::_gamestate::field' uses undefined class 'std::array<std::array<TicTacToe<int>::_player,3>,3>'
1>C:\AlphaBetaNegamax\TicTacToe.h(20): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'TicTacToe<int>::_gamestate' being compiled
1>C:\AlphaBetaNegamax\Source.cpp(3): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'TicTacToe<int>' being compiled
1>C:\AlphaBetaNegamax\TicTacToe.h(24,21): error C2555: 'TicTacToe<int>::getpossiblemoves': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'game<evaluationtype>::getpossiblemoves'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            evaluationtype=int
1>        ]
1>C:\AlphaBetaNegamax\Negamax_and_Gamestructure.h(17): message : see declaration of 'game<evaluationtype>::getpossiblemoves'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            evaluationtype=int
1>        ]
```

I know i messed up somewhere with the Inheriting Nested Classes-Part, im not sure where.
Is that something i really shouldnt be doing, or do I have an issue with the structure of the inheritance?

Comment: `game::_move` and `TicTacToe::_move` are two separate classes that have no particular relationship to one another. So the fact that `game::getpossiblemoves()` returns a `std::list<game::_move>` and `TicTacToe::getpossiblemoves` returns a `std::list<TicTacToe::_move>` is a conflict.

Comment: BTW: I don't see a destructor of your game class which is usually not a problem as simply a default destructor will be used. My own virtual classes I build with a virtual destructor that is for your code ```virtual ~game()```.

Comment: This looks like a case where a [mre] is highly recommended (if not required) for clarity. Focus on `getpossiblemoves()` and remove all that is extraneous to that. Also, get rid of the macros since they not only are noise, but often attract noise (in the form of reminders that Macros Are Evil). Shortened names can be handy, but use `typedef` or `using` instead of `#define`.

Comment: Where is the `#include <array>` that is needed for `std::array`? I don't see any #includes.

Comment: I haven't shown any includes to keep the explanation as short as possible.